# More elegant way to do CultureInvariant Double.parse in F#

Tags: f#, locale

I have an array of numbers in string format (e.g. [|"1"; "2"; "3" ...|]) and want to convert them to doubles, however I want to do it in CultureInvariant way. Of course I could do:

```
[|"1"; "2"|] |> Array.map (fun (a) -> Double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

However, is there any way to do it like this:

```
[|"1"; "2"|] |> Array.map Double.Parse
```

, but with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture? This code will look much more readable. In another words, are there any ways to pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to Double.parse in flow, or set CultureInfo.InvariantCulture globally for all program/script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F# `double` and `float` are the same thing, and they both correspond to a C# `double`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2412799/609639).

Therefore you can simply use the `float` operator for this, which handles conversions from many types including strings:

```
[|"1"; "2"|] |> Array.map float
```

The F# conversion operators all sensibly use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` without the need for you to specify it: See [this function](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/4.0.1.13/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4165) from the F# source code used by the `float` operator.

If you want to use C# compatible terminology you can use the `double` operator, which is just an alias for `float`.

If you need a 32-bit float (the C# float), you can use `float32`.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straightforward to define a helper function and use that:

```
let ParseInvariant a = Double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
let b = [|"1"; "2"|] |> Array.map ParseInvariant
```

or define an extension method:

```
type Double with
    static member ParseInvariant a = Double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
let b = [|"1"; "2"|] |> Array.map Double.ParseInvariant
```

Comment: We usually refer to those as extension members in F# because they are not limited to methods :)